# (OpenCV) can't find Core.line in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, opencv

Problem with `Core.line` (OpenCV) it can't be recognized in android studio however i used **Opencv** functions in the same App but it seems that just the Core.line is missing how I can add it to the library. I'm using **Android Studio 1.3.2** and **Opencv SDK v3**.

Comment: the problem solved by changing Core.line to Imgproc.line

Answer (score 22):

In Opencv SDK v3, you should use Imgproc.line instead of Core.line, Core.line does not exist any more.